# Missing formal parameter javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an object. I have to assign `key` and `value` from html fields. But when I am doing that. It is giving an error "missing formal parameter". [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4sgv8j1/2/)

```
<span class="value">
    <input type="checkbox" name="slt" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="slt" value="0" checked="checked">
</span>


<select class="key">
<option value="1">one</option>
</select>


var a= {$('[name="slt"]:checked').val():$('.key').val()}
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thought `{}` is object literal, but it's not, in this case it's actually parsed as a block of code.

Nobody knows what the "object key" is, until the code is executed. Also no one knows whether it is primitive type, or can be (or should be) converted to primitive (object keys must be primitive - string).

As a block, the content is not a legal expression, and it produces error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
//Declare object
var a= {};
//Use Bracket notation
a[$('[name="slt"]:checked').val()] = $('.key').val();

console.log(a)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mk37k6at/)

Comment: Ok, your code is working fine but can you please tell me the reason why object is not accepting the value in like the way I have written it

Comment: @Satpal As an object key it's valid after calculated. It's just not object literal.